# Problema con animaciones SVG html css3

Tags: html5, css3, svg, animación

Hola a todos estoy tratando de manipular un logo exportado en svg con css, y no se que pasa, intento que la animación sea como un spinner, pero al momento de aplicarlo en lugar de girar el engranaje sobre su propio eje, se va del mismo y gira sobre otro eje que no entiendo cual es el problema con esto, hace todo el dia que ando renegando y buscando la solucion y nada, algo pasa desearía saber que, pueden ayudarme con esto?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Presentacion excedentes</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .presentation {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            background: blue;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .cielo svg {
            height: 40%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .logo {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        
        .gear-3 {
            animation: spin 2s infinite;
        }
        
        @keyframes spin {
            from {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            to {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="presentation">

        <div class="logo">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 1958 1512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    
            <g>
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <g>
                            <g id="final">
                                <g>
                                    <g>
                                        <g>
                                            <circle cx="983.316" cy="608.49" r="608.49" style="fill:#f4f4f4;" />
                                            <clipPath id="_clip2">
                                                <circle cx="983.316" cy="608.49" r="608.49" />
                                            </clipPath>
        
                                      
                                            <g>
                                                <path
                                                    d="M825.833,707.935l-115.943,0l-24.87,61.724l-54.725,0l24.324,-61.724l-0.399,0l18.747,-47.395l0.329,0.001l66.942,-169.869l123.152,0l68.232,185.932l73.151,-185.932l75.564,0l-110.314,278.987l-121.928,0l-22.262,-61.724Zm-96.905,-47.252l79.937,0.205l-37.796,-104.796l-42.141,104.591Z"
                                                    style="fill:#403f41;" />
                                                <g>
                                                    <g>
                                                        
                                                    <g class="gear-3">
                                                        <path
                                                            d="M1225.76,737.15c-4.223,-0.36 -8.471,-0.36 -12.694,0c-0.691,1.343 -1.207,2.743 -1.55,4.2c-4.651,0.527 -9.231,1.517 -13.662,2.955c-0.977,-1.173 -2.084,-2.222 -3.321,-3.148c-3.969,1.412 -7.797,3.158 -11.436,5.218c-0.008,1.494 0.168,2.968 0.527,4.422c-3.95,2.386 -7.622,5.161 -10.957,8.278c-1.416,-0.655 -2.894,-1.145 -4.432,-1.471c-2.93,2.904 -5.579,6.05 -7.915,9.403c0.678,1.348 1.511,2.604 2.5,3.767c-2.465,3.773 -4.503,7.783 -6.08,11.962c-1.577,-0.008 -3.132,0.158 -4.668,0.497c-1.31,3.82 -2.255,7.744 -2.824,11.725c1.228,0.936 2.554,1.725 3.977,2.366c-0.493,4.413 -0.493,8.863 0,13.277c-1.423,0.641 -2.749,1.43 -3.977,2.366c0.569,3.981 1.514,7.905 2.824,11.725c1.536,0.339 3.091,0.505 4.668,0.497c1.577,4.179 3.615,8.188 6.08,11.962c-0.989,1.163 -1.822,2.418 -2.5,3.767c2.336,3.352 4.985,6.499 7.915,9.403c1.538,-0.326 3.016,-0.816 4.432,-1.471c3.335,3.117 7.007,5.891 10.957,8.278c-0.359,1.454 -0.535,2.928 -0.527,4.421c3.639,2.061 7.467,3.807 11.436,5.218c1.237,-0.926 2.344,-1.975 3.321,-3.147c4.431,1.438 9.011,2.428 13.662,2.954c0.343,1.458 0.859,2.858 1.55,4.201c4.223,0.36 8.471,0.36 12.694,0c0.69,-1.343 1.207,-2.743 1.55,-4.201c4.651,-0.526 9.23,-1.516 13.662,-2.954c0.977,1.172 2.083,2.221 3.32,3.147c3.97,-1.411 7.797,-3.157 11.437,-5.218c0.007,-1.493 -0.168,-2.967 -0.527,-4.421c3.949,-2.387 7.622,-5.161 10.956,-8.278c1.417,0.655 2.895,1.145 4.433,1.471c2.93,-2.904 5.579,-6.051 7.915,-9.403c-0.678,-1.349 -1.511,-2.604 -2.5,-3.767c2.465,-3.774 4.503,-7.783 6.08,-11.962c1.576,0.008 3.132,-0.158 4.667,-0.497c1.31,-3.82 2.256,-7.744 2.825,-11.725c-1.228,-0.936 -2.554,-1.725 -3.977,-2.366c0.493,-4.414 0.493,-8.864 0,-13.277c1.423,-0.641 2.749,-1.43 3.977,-2.366c-0.569,-3.981 -1.515,-7.905 -2.825,-11.725c-1.535,-0.339 -3.091,-0.505 -4.667,-0.497c-1.577,-4.179 -3.615,-8.189 -6.08,-11.962c0.989,-1.163 1.822,-2.419 2.5,-3.767c-2.336,-3.353 -4.985,-6.499 -7.915,-9.403c-1.538,0.326 -3.016,0.816 -4.433,1.471c-3.334,-3.117 -7.007,-5.892 -10.956,-8.278c0.359,-1.454 0.534,-2.928 0.527,-4.422c-3.64,-2.06 -7.467,-3.806 -11.437,-5.218c-1.237,0.926 -2.343,1.975 -3.32,3.148c-4.432,-1.438 -9.011,-2.428 -13.662,-2.955c-0.343,-1.457 -0.86,-2.857 -1.55,-4.2Zm-6.347,46.017c12.114,0 21.95,9.318 21.95,20.795c0,11.478 -9.836,20.796 -21.95,20.796c-12.115,0 -21.95,-9.318 -21.95,-20.796c0,-11.477 9.835,-20.795 21.95,-20.795Z"
                                                            style="fill:#403f41;" />
                                                    </g>
                                                </g>
                                            </g>
                                        </g>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
        </div>
    </section>
    


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución:

```
.gear-3 {
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: spin 2s infinite;
}
```

Utilizo `transform-origin: center center;` para que el engranaje gire alrededor del centro. 
También utilizo `transform-box: fill-box;`. De esta manera le digo al `.gear-3` que gire alrededor de *su* centro y no alrededor del centro del lienzo SVG.

En el CSS he cambiado la anchura del `.logo` ya que quería ver el engranaje. Cambialo a lo que tu necesitas.

También en el SVG hice algunos cambios ya que tu código tiene un gran número de grupos inútiles y un elemento `<clipPath>` que no hace nada. 
Para eliminar los espacios vacíos alrededor del logo he cambiado el valor del atributo `viewBox`. Tu puedes utilizar el SVG que tenías antes.

Espero que sea útil.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
.presentation {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  width:100vh;
}
.gear-3 {
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: spin 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="presentation">
  <div class="logo">
    <svg viewBox="374 0 1217 1217">
      <g id="final">
        <g>
          <circle cx="983.316" cy="608.49" r="608.49" style="fill:#f4f4f4;" />
         <g>
          <path d="M825.833,707.935l-115.943,0l-24.87,61.724l-54.725,0l24.324,-61.724l-0.399,0l18.747,-47.395l0.329,0.001l66.942,-169.869l123.152,0l68.232,185.932l73.151,-185.932l75.564,0l-110.314,278.987l-121.928,0l-22.262,-61.724Zm-96.905,-47.252l79.937,0.205l-37.796,-104.796l-42.141,104.591Z" style="fill:" />
         <g class="gear-3" id="kk">
              <path d="M1225.76,737.15c-4.223,-0.36 -8.471,-0.36 -12.694,0c-0.691,1.343 -1.207,2.743 -1.55,4.2c-4.651,0.527 -9.231,1.517 -13.662,2.955c-0.977,-1.173 -2.084,-2.222 -3.321,-3.148c-3.969,1.412 -7.797,3.158 -11.436,5.218c-0.008,1.494 0.168,2.968 0.527,4.422c-3.95,2.386 -7.622,5.161 -10.957,8.278c-1.416,-0.655 -2.894,-1.145 -4.432,-1.471c-2.93,2.904 -5.579,6.05 -7.915,9.403c0.678,1.348 1.511,2.604 2.5,3.767c-2.465,3.773 -4.503,7.783 -6.08,11.962c-1.577,-0.008 -3.132,0.158 -4.668,0.497c-1.31,3.82 -2.255,7.744 -2.824,11.725c1.228,0.936 2.554,1.725 3.977,2.366c-0.493,4.413 -0.493,8.863 0,13.277c-1.423,0.641 -2.749,1.43 -3.977,2.366c0.569,3.981 1.514,7.905 2.824,11.725c1.536,0.339 3.091,0.505 4.668,0.497c1.577,4.179 3.615,8.188 6.08,11.962c-0.989,1.163 -1.822,2.418 -2.5,3.767c2.336,3.352 4.985,6.499 7.915,9.403c1.538,-0.326 3.016,-0.816 4.432,-1.471c3.335,3.117 7.007,5.891 10.957,8.278c-0.359,1.454 -0.535,2.928 -0.527,4.421c3.639,2.061 7.467,3.807 11.436,5.218c1.237,-0.926 2.344,-1.975 3.321,-3.147c4.431,1.438 9.011,2.428 13.662,2.954c0.343,1.458 0.859,2.858 1.55,4.201c4.223,0.36 8.471,0.36 12.694,0c0.69,-1.343 1.207,-2.743 1.55,-4.201c4.651,-0.526 9.23,-1.516 13.662,-2.954c0.977,1.172 2.083,2.221 3.32,3.147c3.97,-1.411 7.797,-3.157 11.437,-5.218c0.007,-1.493 -0.168,-2.967 -0.527,-4.421c3.949,-2.387 7.622,-5.161 10.956,-8.278c1.417,0.655 2.895,1.145 4.433,1.471c2.93,-2.904 5.579,-6.051 7.915,-9.403c-0.678,-1.349 -1.511,-2.604 -2.5,-3.767c2.465,-3.774 4.503,-7.783 6.08,-11.962c1.576,0.008 3.132,-0.158 4.667,-0.497c1.31,-3.82 2.256,-7.744 2.825,-11.725c-1.228,-0.936 -2.554,-1.725 -3.977,-2.366c0.493,-4.414 0.493,-8.864 0,-13.277c1.423,-0.641 2.749,-1.43 3.977,-2.366c-0.569,-3.981 -1.515,-7.905 -2.825,-11.725c-1.535,-0.339 -3.091,-0.505 -4.667,-0.497c-1.577,-4.179 -3.615,-8.189 -6.08,-11.962c0.989,-1.163 1.822,-2.419 2.5,-3.767c-2.336,-3.353 -4.985,-6.499 -7.915,-9.403c-1.538,0.326 -3.016,0.816 -4.433,1.471c-3.334,-3.117 -7.007,-5.892 -10.956,-8.278c0.359,-1.454 0.534,-2.928 0.527,-4.422c-3.64,-2.06 -7.467,-3.806 -11.437,-5.218c-1.237,0.926 -2.343,1.975 -3.32,3.148c-4.432,-1.438 -9.011,-2.428 -13.662,-2.955c-0.343,-1.457 -0.86,-2.857 -1.55,-4.2Zm-6.347,46.017c12.114,0 21.95,9.318 21.95,20.795c0,11.478 -9.836,20.796 -21.95,20.796c-12.115,0 -21.95,-9.318 -21.95,-20.796c0,-11.477 9.835,-20.795 21.95,-20.795Z" style="fill:#403f41;" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>
```